# PHP/PDO - Flush privileges

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, mysqli, mysql-error-1146

I'm doing some mysql server management with a script that flushes the MySQL users privileges when new privileges are added to a MySQL user.

I'm using the PDO class to do my queries, but when I do a simple

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

I get, for

```
$connection->exec('FLUSH PRIVILEGES;');
```

and

```
$connection->query('FLUSH PRIVILEGES;');
```

> SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view
>   not found: 1146 Table 'mysql.servers'
>   doesn't exist

Is it possible to do such query with the PDO class or do I have to resort to using mysql(i)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just tried the following portion of code :

```
$dsn = 'mysql:dbname=mysql;host=127.0.0.1';
$user = 'root';
$password = '********';
try {
    $db = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $db->query('flush privileges;');
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    var_dump($e);
}
```

And I don't get any kind of error like the one you are describing.

Are you sure you don't have some problem with you MySQL server ?

Your error message says that table "`mysql.servers`" doesn't exists... But when I look at my local MySQL server, there is such a table -- are you sure your installation/configuration is not "broken" and you didn't delete that table or anything like that ?

BTW, it doesn't seem to be some kind of privilege you're not having : if you try to `flush privileges` without having the required privilege, you get the following error : "`SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1227 Access denied; you need the RELOAD privilege for this operation`"

Comment: @Pascal MARTIN: Thank you, I was indeed having a broken mysql installation, which was fixed with the mysql_fix_privilege_tables command.